# How to extract values from a nested list with a for-loop (or other functions) and add them to a data frame?

Tags: r, for-loop, extract, nested-lists

I am trying to calculate meta-p values for every gene (rownames) across four datasets (columns) and add them to my df as a fifth column. So essentially for now I have 4 p values for every row. I am using the metap package (function sumz), which requires a vector of p values as input. I'm completely new to writing for loops etc so I am rather struggling.

So far I managed to apply the sumz function over every gene (so over every row).
First, I just pulled the adjusted p values that I was interested in into a df:

`df <- df.all[,c(5,10,15,20)]`

Then I used the apply function:

`x <- apply(df, MARGIN = 1, FUN = sumz)`

This created a nested list x, with a sublist for every gene. So my list x has 138 sublists (each called by a specific gene name), and then every gene has four "factors" within it, including the p value that I am interested in.

To get to a single p value: x$gene$p or x[[gene]]$p

Now, I am trying to extract every **p** from the nested list **x** and add it to my df as a fifth column, named "meta_p".

I tried quite a lot of combinatios of for-loops, such as:

```
for (i in 1:length(x)) {
  meta_p <- x[[i]]$p
}
```

or

```
for (i in 1:length(x)) {
  df$meta_p <- x[[i]]$p
}
```

But they don't work and extract just a single value etc.
I would appreciate any help with extracting the p values from my nested list. Ideally with an explanation as I would really like to understand for-loops.

Best,

K

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with `sapply` :

```
df$meta_p <- sapply(x,`[[`, 'p')
```

Comment: Thanks for the very quick response! It worked, thank you very much